# How to set mfc c++ editbox repeatedly?

Tags: c++, mfc

I selected multiple files from desktop.

```
CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, 
                    _T("*.txt"), 
                    NULL, 
                    OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, 
                    _T(" (*.txt)|*.txt|"));

fileDlg.DoModal();
POSITION pos(fileDlg.GetStartPosition());

while (pos)
{
    CString pathName1(fileDlg.GetNextPathName(pos));
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDITReference, pathName1);
    Sleep(2.0 * 1000);
}
```

It's very simple code which should show the file paths after every 2 seconds. If I select 10 files, it waits for 20 seconds, then show only the path of the last file selected. It doesn't update after every 2 seconds.

Could someone help me with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is (slowly) changing the text in the dialog item - but the dialog doesn't get repainted until your function exits.  You need to cal `UpdateWindow` after the call to `SetDlgItemText`

Comment: This merely resolves the immediate issue of updating the window. It doesn't address the bigger issue: An unresponsive UI. While the function is executing, the UI will not respond to user input. This really needs to be modeled around Windows' event-based architecture (e.g. by using a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632592.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable:  Very good point.  Do you want to add a separate answer about that, or shall I update mine?   (I had subconsciously assumed that the OP knew that this was only a quick hack.  Given that he is asking the question, that is almost certainly false - and anyone find the question later is even *less* likely to know this.)

Comment: Since you already posted an answer, it would introduce less noise and keep this site more focused, if you simply added the information to your existing answer.

Comment: What if you posted a user message to update the interface? Otherwise you have to do a loop and peek and pump the messages to keep it alive.